# I need to echo all tokens when am done

Tags: php, loops

The issue is about echoing all tokens after completing the loop, I don't seem to be getting it.

```php
 for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6);
    $token = bin2hex($token);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO voucher (generator,pin,date)
            VALUES('$username', '$token', '$datenow')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

        //echo tokens

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example from [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), you can use it as a reference.

```php
for ($i = -1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($i, $cstrong);
    $hex   = bin2hex($bytes);
    echo "Length: Bytes: $i y Hex: " . strlen($hex) . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($hex);
    var_dump($cstrong);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```